# Can't get WebApp to initialize on Eclipse's Tomcat [was working previously]

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I cannot initialize my app on Eclipse's tomcat. It was working fine 8 hours ago. I left it unattended.

Upon my return I had some unrelated issues where a type from the same package could not be resolved so I: 1. Cleaned Maven, 2. Updated project 3. Deleted / RE-added server 4. Rebooted Eclipse

After this the app will not initialize on tomcat. I ran maven build and that built .war if that makes any difference.

Please see server initialization log, servlet initializer, web.xml below.
Some notes:
 - I did not edit my pom.xml

- App runs on annotations not xml
- The sysout's on servlet initializer don't get printed so it doesn't get to that stage.

> Servlet Init

```
package domain.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        System.out.println("Security Servlet init");
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        System.out.println("Config Servlet init");
        return new Class[] { ConfigClass.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

> Tomcat log

```
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:applicationform' did not find a matching property.
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 20 2018 17:32:21 UTC
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.10.0
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\OUYanis\Documents\live\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\OUYanis\Documents\live\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\OUYanis\Documents\live\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Acer\Remote Files\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\OUYanis\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\sts-3.9.5.RELEASE;;.]
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2540 ms
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:21 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 29, 2018 4:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13723 ms
```

> Edit, Deployment Assembly

[image: EDIT]

Comment: Have you verified that on your project properties, you have the right classpath set. Look at `Deployment Assembly`

Comment: @nmorenor please see edit at the bottom of the post. I am unsure what it should look like? Ah, I realised... It hasn't got Maven dependencies, right?

Comment: :@nmorenor You nailed it! I cannot believe I missed that. Please post an answer for those sweet points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yanis, I'm glad that did work for you, I actually had the same issue on my side and it did take me a time to figure out that the setting that I had to change was the `Deployment Assembly` like the screenshot you've posted there.